# Custom dialogs inside user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

We have a custom dialog (derived from `ContentControl`) that tends to sit inside a `UserControl`.  The Dialog itself has functionality such that it can be closed.  The closing functionality, on inspection, only seems to close the Dialog itself and NOT its parent container.

```
public void CloseDialog()
{
    Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    if (null != DialogClosedEvent)
        DialogClosedEvent();
}
```

Our user controls are usually created like so

```
<UserControl>
    <toolkit:OurDialog ... />
</UserControl>
```

Now this means when we close a dialog, we are left with many `UserControl`s with nothing in side of them. This all works as you'd expect - in terms of being able to view and close dialogs - but will this have an affect on performance leaving the empty UserControls? If so what is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you, at times, subsequently "opening" these dialogs later?

Comment: We will be yes.. we havent got to that point at the moment though - I expect it will become a problem when we do!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to be "opening" these dialogs again later, at times, you're going to need to leave it the way it is. I don't expect that you'll see any real performance issues. I mean "closing" it and "opening" it doesn't really add anything more to the markup. You're just making it invisible. So you're not really proliferating them at runtime.

In short, have a look at the memory footprint when the `Window` loads and if you're satisfied with that then you're good - it's not going to change by making these dialogs visible vs. invisible.